# Cannot create composed task via DSL when logging is on

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm having this security configuration:

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: true                                                     
    realm: Whatever
  user:
    name: some-name
    password: super-secret
    role: VIEW, CREATE, MANAGE
```

When I try to create new composed task by pasting code into DSL view, I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "timestamp":"2017-12-05T12:34:07.958Z",
  "status":403,
  "error":"Forbidden",
  "message":"Access is denied",
  "path":"/tools/parseTaskTextToGraph"
}
```

Should I add some more roles for user? Of course if I'm not using security everything works.

Spring dataflow version is `1.2.2.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been addressed via: [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#1850](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1850).

It is already merged to `master`, so please try the [1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started) bits and let us know if you see any other anomalies.

Thanks for reporting it.